# APScheduler - ImportWarning but code still runs. What is wrong?

Tags: python, apscheduler

My code follows the example from [APScheduler Docs](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html#examples) but I changed its format  to follow mine. It works no problem. "Hello World" is printed every 10 seconds.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import datetime

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

class Class1:

    def job_function():
        print("Hello World")

class Class2:        

    def go():

        sched = BlockingScheduler()

        # Schedule job_function to be called every 10 seconds
        sched.add_job(Classy.job_function, 'interval', seconds = 10)

        sched.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Class2.go()
```

My actual code however, does not work so well.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import time
import praw
import OAuth2Util
import redditNewsBot
import redditFreeGameBot
import redditWorldNewsBot
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


class Aggregate:

    def aggr()
        ...

    def x():
        print('x')

class RunSchedule:

    def go():

        sched = BlockingScheduler()

        # Schedule job_function to be called every ten seconds
        sched.add_job(Aggregate.x, 'interval', seconds = 10)

        sched.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    RunSchedule.go()
```

Everything will run at the specified interval but I get all this first:

```
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py:415: ImportWarning: Not importing directory

C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits: missing __init___warnings.warn(msg.format(portions[0]), ImportWarning)

C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py:415: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 

c:\users\nick\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits: missing __init___warnings.warn(msg.format(portions[0]), ImportWarning)

C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py:415: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 

C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\zope: missing __init___warnings.warn(msg.format(portions[0]), ImportWarning)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `praw`.

I imported it to the test script behind `datetime` and `from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler` and it ran error free.

I then moved it in front of the latter and it threw the errors.

In order to run error free from `apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingSchedulerhad` to move to the very front of the import list. `time` and `datetime` can be in front without errors as well.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import praw
import time
import datetime
import OAuth2Util
import redditNewsBot
import redditFreeGameBot
import redditWorldNewsBot
```